# Q: How to find same and similar string values in different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database, each table has column with names. How to compare these tables columns and how to find these names what has exact matches and these names, which are similar in table1 and table2?

For example:

table1

```
column1
---------------------
Tom Hawky
Antony Hendric Formen
Cathy Cassy
Bill Gates
Mary Diore
```

table2

```
column1
----------------------
Christopher Fridricson
Ken Lovely
Tom Hawky
Anthony Foreman
Chati Cassei
```

Result should come out with this:

```
table1 - table2
Tom Hawky - Tom Hawky
Antony Hendric Formen - Anthony Henrich Foreman
Cathy Cassy - Chati Cassei
```

Comment: What does "similar" mean?  You need a very specific definition before anyone can answer your question.  Finding exact matches is easy, even ignoring case is easy,  but finding similar names is a whole new can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to do the following:

1) Split the names into some temporary tables, so that comparison can be done much easier

2) Construct a query that tries to find matches based on some distance

**1) Splitting into words**

**Setup**

```
-- drop table Table1
create table Table1 
(
    Id1 INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Column1 NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
GO

insert into Table1 (Column1)
VALUES ('Tom Hawky'), ('Antony Hendric Formen'), ('Cathy Cassy'), ('Bill Gates'), ('Mary Diore')
GO

-- drop table Table2
create table Table2
(
    Id2 INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Column2 NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
GO

insert into Table2 (Column2)
VALUES ('Christopher Fridricson'), ('Ken Lovely'), ('Tom Hawky'), ('Anthony Foreman'), ('Chati Cassei'), ('Tom X')
GO

select * from Table1
GO

select * from Table2
GO
```

**Split function**

There are several [split functions](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) that can be used and I have chosen the XML way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

**Split the words**

```
drop table #T1Words
Go

create table #T1Words (Id1 INT NOT NULL, Word NVARCHAR(100))
GO

insert into #T1Words 
select T1.Id1, X1.Item
from Table1 T1
    cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_XML (T1.Column1, N' ') X1
GO

drop table #T2Words
GO 

create table #T2Words (Id2 INT NOT NULL, Word NVARCHAR(200))
GO

insert into #T2Words 
select T2.Id2, X2.Item
from Table2 T2
    cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_XML (T2.Column2, N' ') X2
GO
```

**Select using some distance**

One distance that can be used is [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). In order to use it in SQL, it must be implemented in CLR, otherwise it is very slow. Something like this:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = false)]
public static int Levenshtein(SqlString S1, SqlString S2)
{
    if (S1.IsNull)
        S1 = new SqlString("");

    if (S2.IsNull)
        S2 = new SqlString("");

    int maxLen = 4096;

    // keeping only the first part of the string (performance reasons)
    String SC1 = S1.Value.ToUpper();
    String SC2 = S2.Value.ToUpper();

    if (SC1.Length > maxLen)
        SC1 = SC1.Remove(maxLen);
    if (SC2.Length > maxLen)
        SC2 = SC2.Remove(maxLen);

    int n = SC1.Length;
    int m = SC2.Length;

    short[,] d = new short[n + 1, m + 1];
    int cost = 0;

    if (n + m == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (m == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (short i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        d[i, 0] = i;

    for (short j = 0; j <= m; j++)
        d[0, j] = j;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            if (SC1[i - 1] == SC2[j - 1])
                cost = 0;
            else
                cost = 1;

            d[i, j] = (short) System.Math.Min(System.Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1), d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }

    // double percentage = System.Math.Round((1.0 - ((double)d[n, m] / (double)System.Math.Max(n, m))) * 100.0, 2);
    // return percentage;
    return d[n, m];
}

-- SQL to actually create scalar function that calls CLR code
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Levenshtein(@S1 nvarchar(max), @S2 nvarchar(max))
    RETURNS INT as EXTERNAL NAME ClrUtils.StoredFunctions.Levenshtein
GO

-- CLR must be enabled for database
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**2) The query**

```
select T1.Id1, T1.Column1, T2.Id2, T2.Column2
from Table1 T1
    cross join Table2 T2 
where EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #T1Words T1W
        JOIN #T2Words T2W ON [dbo].[Levenshtein](T2W.Word, T1W.Word) < 3   -- T2W.Word = T1W.Word
    WHERE T1W.Id1 = T1.Id1
        AND T2W.Id2 = T2.Id2
)
```

Of course, you must set your threshold based on the acceptable difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.column1 + '-' + table2.column1
from table1 join table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column1
```

Comment: A little explanation about your code would improve your answer drastically.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clearly defined the parameters for determining similarity. But an interesting approach could be to use the `DIFFERENCE` function. This will compare the phonetic representation for two strings (using the `SOUNDEX` function) and return a value from 0 to 4, with 4 being the strongest match. So you can try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.column1 + ' - ' + t2.column1 AS 'table1 - table2'
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON DIFFERENCE(t1.column1,t2.column1)>= 3
```

I've set the minimum comparison level to 3, but you can adjust it to best fit your data.